# Changing the vertical distance between a boxed Algorithm and it's caption

Tags: spacing, algorithm2e

When I create an algorithm using the `algorithm2e` package, the distance between the caption at the bottom of the `boxed` algorithm is too small!

```
\usepackage[lined,boxed]{algorithm2e}

  \begin{algorithm}[h]
    \If{Condition} {
      Do something \;
    }
    \caption{Algoritm...}
  \end{algorithm}
```

How do I increase the space between the box and the caption?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After looking through the [documentation](//mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/algorithm2e/doc/algorithm2e.pdf), I found on section 9.2.2:

> `\AlCapSkip` is the dimension of the distance between algorithm body and caption in `plain` and `boxed` mode. You can change by hands or by using `\SetAlCapSkip{0ex}`.

So adding `\SetAlCapSkip{1ex}` fixed the problem and it didn't change the captions from normal figures.